# Issues with javascript internal functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm having an issue using an internal function function.

```
this.init = function () {

  var size = this.ref;
  var wall = this.element;
  var id = this.id;
  var initRef = this.init;

  this.update(id, size, wall, initRef);
}


this.update = function (id, size, wall, init) {

  $.get(url, "cpart=" + id + "&ref=" + size, (function (wall, size, init) {
    return function (data) {
      if (data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        size = response["psize"];
        wall.append(response["msg"]);
        wall.scrollTop($(document).height());
      }

      init();
    }
  })(wall, size, init));
}
```

The issue i am having is the second iteration, the variables in the ajax request are undefined and i am not sure why that happens. When the function is called the first time it works, however the second time, variables and size are undefined.

Thanks for the help ahead of time

Comment: There is no argument for "url" in update function? is this declared globally?

Comment: The is not a good use of anonymous functions and self calling functions. you made it overly complicated

Comment: Yeah it is complicated but, i don't know how else to accomplish what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the format of you get statement should like this :

```
$.get(url, {cpart: id, ref: size}, (function (wall, size, init) {
   // existing stuff
});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try *this* instead:

```
this.update = function (id, size, wall, init) {

    $.get(url, "cpart=" + id + "&ref=" + size, (function (self, wall, size, init) {
        return function (data) {
            if (data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                size = response["psize"];
                wall.append(response["msg"]);
                wall.scrollTop($(document).height());
            }

            init.apply(self);
        }
    })(this, wall, size, init));
}
```

Since you're calling init without really specifying an activation object, anything could be happening.

---

**Update:**
I'm now reading your code with more attention.

While, I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to achieve, here's a revised version:

```
this.update = function () {
    var self = this;

    $.get(url, "cpart=" + id + "&ref=" + size, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            self.size = response["psize"];
            self.wall.append(response["msg"]);
            self.wall.scrollTop($(document).height());
        }

        init.call(self);
    });
}
```

Notice that I'm no longer passing arguments to `update`, and instead I'm using directly the properties from the object. I keep a reference to object in the `self` variable, which will be accessible from the anonymous function we give to `$.get()` because it's declared in the function that surrounds it (ie, the "update" function).

---

**Update 2**

You're calling init, which calls update, which will result in init being called again! Don't you think there should be a way to break that cycle?
You'll be hammering both the server and the user's browser.

I think it's for the best if you just tells us what you're trying to achieve.

---

**Update 3**

Feels like I'm doing your job for you  :J

```
// If you're writing a "class", there's got
// to be a constructor somewhere:

function YourClass(id, ref, element) {
    // These need to come from somewhere...
    this.id = id;
    this.ref = ref; 
    this.element = element;
}


// Now we set your "class methods" on YourClass.prototype,
// so they can be shared among all the instances of YourClass.
// Create instances like this: 
// obj = new YourClass();

YourClass.prototype.init = function() {
    // You want to give these properties
    // alternate names, I'll respect that.
    // (notice obj.ref won't ever be updated, but obj.size will)
    this.size = this.ref;
    this.wall = this.element;
    this.update();
}


YourClass.prototype.updateFromData = function(data) {
    // I moved this code to a helper "class method" to make things more clear
    if (data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        this.size = response["psize"];
        this.wall.append(response["msg"]);
        obj.wall.scrollTop($(document).height());
    }
    this.init();
}


YourClass.prototype.update = function() {
    // Not the most elegant way of coding this,
    // but it should be easier to read.        
    function createUpdater(obj){
        return function(data){
            obj.updateFromData(data);
        }
    }        
    $.get(url, "cpart=" + this.id + "&ref=" + this.size, createUpdater(this));        
}

// An alternative to the above would simply be this:
// YourClass.prototype.update = function() {
//     $.get(url, "cpart=" + this.id + "&ref=" + this.size, this.updateFromData.bind(this));
// }
```

Comment: I tried that and i got the same results. The reason im trying to pass all of this in the return function of the ajax request is because you cant reference the variables using "this". so i use the init function to get a reference to them, then pass the variables in the function, but i am obviously missing something

Comment: can `that` be used for this problem? putting `that = this` inside the outer function and then `init.apply(that)`

Comment: @mashit You can name the variable whatever you want (as long as it's not a reserved word). "that" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @CBaker I just noticed you seem to be trying to update size that inner function. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Zecc Yeah, what i am trying to do is sort of implement comet programming type style. The client initiates a request to the server and waits for a response and when it returns, it iniates another connnect. Now the issue i am having is updating the variables from the response in my attempt at a javascript class. I tried using a basic object but you can only have once instance which brought me to using a function instead. I tried implement your edited version however i get an error saying self.wall is undefined.

Comment: @Zecc Thanks for the help. I implemented your suggestions and it works much better.